# Relative Height of UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In `RootViewController` am using a UITableView for displaying the content of data. In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I am calling another view controller (`DetailViewController`) to display detailed data. For displaying this detailed data I am using a `UITableview` in the `DetailViewController` also. This table contains one section and only one row.

Now the problem is that I have to adjust the table's height dynamically when I move from `RootViewController` to `DetailViewController`. How can I make the height of the `UITableView` dynamic between the two classes?

Any help would be Appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the UITableViewDelegate method something like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return [TextToDisplay sizeWithFont:/*DESIRED_FONT*/ constrainedToSize:/*YOUR DESIRED_SIZE*/ lineBreakMode:/*DESIRED_LINEBREAKMODE*/].height;
}
```

to get variable heights.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your trying to reuse a `UITableView` between two different `UIViewControllers`. I think your better off having the `RootViewController` have it's own `UITableView` which is set to a dynamic height and width using the `UIView autoresizingMask` property. Then when you select a row and push on the `DetailViewController` in a `UINavigationController` stack it would have it'd own `UITableView` to display the detail information your trying to show.

This interaction technique is used throughout other iPhone applications like Mail. If I misunderstood your question please let me know.